# Docker and Cypress - CypressError: `cy.type()` can only accept a string or number. You passed in: `undefined`

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm trying to use cypress with docker.
Locally with cypress everything works fine, but on docker I get some errors.

This is the code:

```
import { generateUser } from '../../utils';

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  return false;
});

describe('Login', () => {
  it('should be successful', () => {
    const user = generateUser({
      email: Cypress.env('username'),
      password: Cypress.env('password'),
    });
    cy.login(user);
    cy.location('pathname').should('include', 'map');
  });
```

Locally it pass the login test normally, but on docker I got an error:

```
CypressError: `cy.type()` can only accept a string or number. You passed in: `undefined`
```

Does anybody know what can cause this?

---

**Extra info from comment**

I have a command `generateUser` which I call in the start and it is like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user) => { 
  cy.visit('/login'); 
  cy.get('#email').type(user.email); 
  cy.get('#password').type(user.password); 
  cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click(); 
});
```

And in the `config.json` I have the `env`, where are stored the username and password, this normally works, but in docker won't.

Comment: It's caused by sending `undefined` as a parameter to `cy.type()`, the error message does not lie (most likely anyway). I assume you use `cy.type()` incorrectly inside `cy.login()` custom command.

Comment: As @pavelsaman says, inside the `cy.login(user)` custom command you have `cy.get(...).type(user.email)` and it fails because `user.email` is undefined. So most likely `Cypress.env('username')` is not returning a value when running in the docker environment.

Comment: @pavelsaman @Steve Zodiac 
Thank you for the reply!

I have two more things if it means something.

One I have a command generateUser which I call in the start and it is like this:
`Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user) => {
  cy.visit('/login');
  cy.get('#email').type(user.email);
  cy.get('#password').type(user.password);
  cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();
});`
And in the config.json I have the env, where are stored the username and password, this normally works, but in docker won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few assumptions, because not all details are shown...

Inside the `cy.login(user)` custom command you have a line similar to

```js
cy.get(...).type(user.email)
```

and it fails because `user.email` is undefined.

Most likely `Cypress.env('username')` is not returning a value when running in the docker environment.

Here is a sample docker run command that passes in environment variables,

```
docker run -it -v /$PWD://e2e -w //e2e cypress/included:4.5.0 \
  -e username=my-secret-username, password=my-secret-password
```

Since the username and password are in `cypress.json`, are you copying that file into docker?

Comment: Yes I'm coping all that is in the folder locally to docker.
I found a solution to this for now, I've used an user that is static an put it in fixtures and now everything is working well.

Thank you very much for your help! :)